# Setup WordPress as a sub folder in Magento 2 directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento2, subdirectory, fishpig

I have Magento 2 and want to setup WordPress in a subfolder, so it will be accessed via magento2.url/blog

I know about Fishpig but for my situation, it will not work because WordPress site has a lot of custom post types which is not supported by FishPig integration by default.

Right now if I tried to access magento2.url/blog it shows a 404 error Magento 2 page.

I modified .htaccess in WordPress subfolder to this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But it not helps and home page for WordPress still shows a 404 Magento 2 page. I think I need to modify .htaccess in Magento 2 but not really sure how.

Comment: you can use magento wordpress plugin for this result

Comment: I noticed that I can't use Fishpig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .htaccess is irrelevant when integrating WordPress into Magento. This file only applies when accessing WordPress directly (ie. for a WordPress Admin request).

Here are basic installation instructions:

- Install WordPress in a sub-directory of Magento called wp.
- If you use the pub directory to display Magento, either install WordPress at pub/wp or create a symlink at pub/wp to point to the actual wp folder.
- Check the wp_options table for the home and siteurl values. The siteurl value should be the /wp URL and the home option should be your /blog URL

This is all you need to do to integrate WordPress at /blog.

The .htaccess file has no impact here, however you should change /blog/ to /wp/ in the .htaccess for WordPress. The correct value is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

For a full installation guide, see [this link](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/installation/).

Answer (score 1):

For case if using Apache.

1. install Magento
2. install Wordpress to subfolder **blog**
3. add to .htaccess & pud/.htaccess following code

   `RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /blog/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]`
4. In folder pub create symbol link like

   *ln -s /var/html/blog /var/html/pub/blog*

Answer (score -1):

As answered on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/53757 you should install WordPress outside the Magento directory.

Despite of that, in your case you must edit Magento `.htaccess` because WP can't be accessed wich explains the Magento 404 error.

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*) /blog/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You do not need to modify the Magento .htaccess at all to integrate WordPress. The correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/59263090/1952727